# How to find multiplicative inverse of $17$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

Say I want to find the multiplicative inverse of $17$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$?

How to do it?

First thing to check is $\gcd(17,26)=1$ so yes they are relatively prime.

I don't really understand Euclid's algorithm to give a solution... Can anyone give an example of how to use his algorithm to find solution? Can be different numbers than what I listed above- just need to see example in action.

Many thanks.

Comment: sorry, typo- should be 17

Comment: It's not Euclid's algorithm, it's Euclid's _extended_ algorithm that gives you a solution. The extension entails, while using the normal algorithm, also keeping track of all the subtractions you do, and in the end it gives you $m, n$ such that $17m + 26n = 1$, and that $m$ you see there (reduced modulo $26$, of course) is your inverse.

Comment: @JBKing That linked duplicate doesn't have any answers that address the extended euclidean algorithm.

Comment: Is using Euclid's algorithm required? The question in the title and the first couple of questions in the post don't mention that which is where I could think the question I linked may be useful as other ways to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the algorithm goes as follows.

$$\begin{align*}26 &= 1 \cdot 17 + \color{red}9 \\ 17 &= 1 \cdot 9 + \color{red}8 \\ 9 &= 1\cdot 8 + \color{red}1. \end{align*}$$

So going back up and isolating the remainders we have $$ \color{red}1 = 9 - \color{red}8 = 9 - (17 - 9) = 2\cdot \color{red}9 - 17 = 2\cdot(26 - 17) - 17 = 2\cdot 26 - 3\cdot 17.$$

And so we find that $1 \equiv (-3)\cdot 17 \mod 26$, i.e., the inverse of $17$ is $-3 \equiv 23 \mod 26$.

Comment: may i ask why we are subtracting from 9 (or some multiple of 9) in the last step? is it because it is the first remainder we got?

Comment: @Chio You mean when we write that $1 = 9 - 8$? It's the only way we can get to $1$ using the quotients and remainders we have. Think about going "back up" the algorithm: we start at the last line and then go up line after line.

Answer (score 1):

Let's find $X$:

$17X \equiv 1 \pmod{26}$

$-9X \equiv 1 \pmod{26}$

$9X \equiv -1 \pmod{26}$

$27X \equiv -3 \pmod{26}$

$X \equiv -3 \pmod{26}$

Answer (score 0):

Note $51=17\times 3$. Then $17*3=51\equiv(-1)\pmod{26}$. Thus $17*(-3)\equiv 1\pmod{26}$ and $-3\equiv23\pmod{26}$. Therefore $17*23\equiv 1\pmod{26}$

Answer (score 0):

We can also do this using Euler's theorem and exponentiation by squaring, complexity is logarithmic over the modulus.

First calculate for powers of two, we use this later: $17^2\equiv 3, 17^4 \equiv9, 17^8\equiv 3$

Now use Euler's theorem to see :
$17^{-1}\equiv17^{\varphi(26)-1}=17^{11}=17\times17^2\times17^7\equiv17\times 3\times 3\equiv 23$.

Comment: In my experience this is quicker to implement.